# How can i set x-axis with respect to seconds e.g 12:01:00. using chart_flutter line chart

Tags: flutter

[This is my line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzFEm.jpg)

**below is my code for ploting line chart which is working for day,hour,minute but not for seconds **

```
domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(tickFormatterSpec:
                          new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
                              hour: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
                                  format: 'Hms', transitionFormat: 'Hms')))
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: sir, I want to implement line chart using chart_flutter. its working but x -axis scale showing only two values. As my data is between 00:00:00 to 23:59:00. i want it to show all the values on the x-axis which i am providing. its only showing two values which is a range between two end points ..you can see my screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide tickprovider spec too Let me know if it helps

`domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec( tickProviderSpec:                              charts.AutoDateTimeTickProviderSpec(includeTime:true), tickFormatterSpec: charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec( day: charts.TimeFormatterSpec( format: 'hh:mm', transitionFormat: 'hh:mm', ), ), ),`